# How can i call unity3d functions from wp8 ui thread?

Tags: windows-phone-8, unity-game-engine

I tried many ways but nothing works fine. I am novice at programming and multuthreading operations is steel hard for me to understand.
In Windows Metro i can use:

```
Appcallbacks.instance.InvokeOnAppThread
```

How can i do it in wp8?

This work, but throw C++ exception, and i know that it's not right way

```
Deployment.Current.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(()=>UnityApp.BeginInvoke(new UnityPlayer.Action(() => { my functions })));
```

Answer (score 0):

Unity3d is not thread safe and you can't call it from any other thread, other than the main thread: http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/7524/is-the-unity-api-threadsafe.html

Answer (score 0):

You must compile a native WP8 dll and invoke the Dispatcher from there.  Make a static WP8 method with a callback that Unity code can use.

Comment: It is possible with 2 ways.
1. Direct Communication with unity compiled visual studio project.
2. Make plugin (DLL) of all the native functionalities and import them to unity and call funcitons from there.

In which way you had tried?

And in which way you want this?